# WPF XamDataGrid doesn't update until leaving current cell

Tags: c#, wpf, xamdatagrid

I have SEVERAL XamDataGrids in my application, and I want all of them to enable the respective Save buttons as soon as the user changes a checkbox in them.  This currently doesn't happen until I leave the cell or press enter etc, because the cell is still in edit mode.  I know how to fix this using a post I found in code-behind:

```
private void XamDataGrid_CellChanged(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.CellChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cell.Record.SetCellValue(e.Cell.Field, e.Editor.Value, true);
        }
```

But how can i handle this for ALL my grid across the app, without putting this in code-behind for every grid?  I am using MVVM and would prefer to not have any code behind, if possible.  If I have to, i will, but i defintitely don't want it in the code behind in 17 different files with grids.  Maybe a behavior?

Comment: This sounds like you need to add the `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` property to a value of `PropertyChanged` on your `Binding`s... it sounds like they are currently set to `LostFocus`?

Comment: sounds like but isn't, the cell in a xamdatagrid is "still in edit mode", so setting UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged has no effect, in fact, that's the default i belive

Comment: You can have code-behind in MVVM. It just can't be business logic.

Comment: You could create a new class and inherit `XamDataGrid`. With that, you could override the protected method `OnCellChanged` and add the implementation you posted. That would remove the necessity of adding code-behind to all your files.

Comment: that's a good idea and probably what i will do.  i still want to hear from someone who can tell me if I can( (should?) accomplish this via a behavior and how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the [DataItemUpdateTrigger](http://help.infragistics.com/Doc/WPF/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v14.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.FieldSettings~DataItemUpdateTrigger.html) to [OnCellValueChange](http://help.infragistics.com/Doc/WPF/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v14.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataItemUpdateTrigger.html).

**Default value for all fields in a XamDataGrid**

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings 
        DataItemUpdateTrigger="OnCellValueChange" />
</igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
```

- I believe this could easily be applied as a style for all XamDataGrids.

**For an individual Field**

```
<igDP:Field Label="" Name="IsSelected" >
    <igDP:Field.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings DataItemUpdateTrigger="OnCellValueChange" />
    </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:Field>
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataItemUpdateTrigger` property is available in `FieldSettings` class in NetAdvantage 2013 v. 2 or later.